# Existence of free operators, independent and with given distributions

Tags: pr.probability, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, free-probability

Excuse me if the question is not appropriate for Mathoverflow. I havs asked it in math.stackexchange, but did not get any response. And so, I dared to put it here. I am trying to learn free probability from scratch, mostly by myself. I am trying to prove the following result.

> If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are compactly supported probability measures, then
>   there exists a $C^*$ probability space $(\mathcal{A}, \phi)$ and self
>   adjoint $a,~b\in \mathcal{A}$ which are free independent and have
>   distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

I was told that this can be easily proved using free products of $*$-probability spaces. But I can not see how it follows. Can someone give me a line of proof, or point out some place where I can get the result? Advanced thanks for any helps/suggestions.

If it is not too much already, can someone suggest some reference from where I can study free probability, possibly from a Physics point of view? (I have already read Terrence Tao's blog notes, and I want to move forward).

Comment: Shameless self referal: Ch5 of Anderson-Guionnet-Zeitouni deals with free probability "from scratch".

Comment: Thanks, Prof. @oferzeitouni Now I know where to look and whom to disturb for free probability :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the C$^*$-algebras $\mathcal A = L^\infty(\mu)$ and $\mathcal B = L^\infty(\nu)$. They are C$^*$-probability spaces when equipped with the states $\phi(c) = \int c \;\mu$ and $\psi(c) = \int c \; d\nu$.
Then the elements $a = z$ and $b=z$ in $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ have distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

Voiculescu defined the **reduced free product** of C$^*$-algebras in his seminal work on free probability
(Operator Algebras and their Connections with Topology and Ergodic Theory
, Lecture Notes in Math. 1132 (1985), Springer Verlag, 556). Though, you can google reduced free product to turn up some more descriptive descriptions. In simple terms this defines a new C$^*$-probability space $(\mathcal A *_r \mathcal B, \phi *_r \psi)$ such that $\mathcal A, \mathcal B \subset \mathcal A *_r \mathcal B$, $\phi *_r\psi|_\mathcal A = \phi$, $\phi *_r \psi|_\mathcal B = \psi$ and, most importantly, $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are freely independent with respect to $\phi *_r \psi$.

Therefore, $a$ and $b \in \mathcal A *_r\mathcal B$ are freely independent with distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Here are some references, though I am not sure if any deal with a physics perspective:

(1) G. Anderson, A. Guionnet, O. Zeitouni, *An introduction to random matrices.*

(2) A. Nica, R. Speicher: *Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability*.

(3) F. Hiai and D. Petz, *The Semicircle Law, Free Random Variables, and Entropy.*

(4) P. Mitchener, *Non-Commutative Probability Theory.*

(5) D. Voiculescu, K. Dykema, A. Nica, *Free random variables.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the list. I have got a copy of Nica and Speicher a day ago. Anyways, I am keeping it open in the hope that some more suggestions may turn up. :)

Comment: some literature with a more physics flavor are for example:

Comment: 1) "Quantum free Yang-Mills on the plane" by Anshelevich and Sengupta, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.2107.pdf, or
2) "Zooming in on local level statistics by supersymmetric extension of free probability" by Mandt and Zirnbauer, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1877.pdf or     3) "Anomalous transport: a mathematical framework" (in particular, chapter 5) by Schulz-Baldes and Bellisard, https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9706239.pdf